# unable to select Chinese word when in landscape mode using android google input

Tags: android, keyboard

Landscape mode; 
Edittext is set with 'imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"';
Google PinYin Input Method;

When I tried to type chinese into a EditText, It shows pinyin without word selections.
Does anyone have idea of how to solve this problem?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

你 好
I'm using a Samsung galaxy s3 with criskelo Rom, android 4.1.1
And I wrote the first paragraph in landscape mode, it worked perfectly. 
You should add more details

Comment: hi, thanks.  more details: Landscape mode; Edittext is set with 'imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"'; Google PinYin Input Method. No matter what chinese word I typed, it can't display word selection area.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the edittext like this:

```java
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"
```

hope can help someone else